# Why doesn't Wimbledon have final set tie break?

Tags: tennis, tie-breaker, wimbledon

Wimbledon is the only tennis grand slam that doesn't have a final set tie break. This means that there is no maximum number of games in the 5th set (for men). Famously John Isner and Nicolas Mahut [played](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships) a 138 game 5th set in 2010.

Without the final set tie break, matches can last far longer than anticipated, causing scheduling problems and leaving the winner of such marathon matches physically exhausted for the next match. So why doesn't Wimbledon have the tie break?

**EDIT**: In 2018 Wimbledon [introduced](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2018/oct/19/wimbledon-fifth-set-tie-break-tennis) a tie break to final set (3rd set for women, 5th for men). If players reach a 12-12 games tie in the final set, a tie breaker will be played to determine the winner of the match. In its first year, this rule came into effect for the very first time in the [finals match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) between Roger Federer and Novak Djokovic.

Comment: Related, or maybe "anti-duplicate": [Why does the US Open have a tiebreaker for the fifth set?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/why-does-the-us-open-have-a-tiebreaker-for-the-fifth-set).

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Wimbledon is not the only grand slam without a final tie-break. The australian open, Roland Garros and Wimbledon all lack a final tie-break. Only the US Open has one (and you can look at the question linked in the question above to see why).

Comment: @Fatalize the Australian and French open have final set tie break for doubles. The US open has the tie break for the singles and the doubles. However, Wimbledon is the only grand slam to not have a final set tie break for the singles or doubles.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Championships,_Wimbledon), on October 19th, 2018, Wimbledon

> announced that a tie-break will be played if the score reaches 12–12 in the final set of any match; this will apply to all competitions including in qualifying, singles and doubles.